# Displaying Only the first x characters of a string in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an output as "2017-11-17T06:06:29.000+0000" I only want the date part just before "T" how can I split it using ruby on rails?

Comment: This answer can be easily googled

Answer (score 2):

You can use `strftime` to print out the required format.
Use  `<%=date.strftime("%F") %>` to print your required format of date.
Here is the required documentation needed for reference: https://apidock.com/ruby/DateTime/strftime

Answer (score 0):

`"2017-11-17T06:06:29.000+0000".first(10)` as more easy to understand
`"2017-11-17T06:06:29.000+0000".split('T').first` as more generic way to split date from time

PS: I've marked your question for moderation, because this question is a basic, that can easily be found in manuals/docs/google.